# overlapping groups in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate "rolling" summary statistics based on a grouping factor.  Is there a nice way to process by (overlapping) groups, based on (say) an ordered factor?

As an example, say I want to calculate the sum of `val` by groups

```
df <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
                 val = rnorm(7))
```

For groups based on `grp`, it's easy:

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(total = sum(val))

# result:
  grp   total
1   a  1.6388
2   b  0.7421
3   c  1.1707
```

However, what I want to do is calculate "rolling" sums for successive groups ("a" & "b", then "b" & "c", etc.). The desired output would be something like this:

```
  grp1 grp2   total
1    a    b  1.6388
2    b    c  0.7421
```

I'm having trouble doing this in dplyr.  In particular, I can't seem to figure out how to get "overlapping" groups - the "b" rows in the above example should end up in *two* output groups.

Comment: Just one clarification... These groups you are talking about are gonna be sorted? What if there are in seq like `a,b,c,a,c,d,b,a` ?

Comment: Yep, they'll be sorted.  In principle they needn't be, the order (i.e. which ones I want paired together) is based on their order as ordered factors, not on their order as rows in the df.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `lag`:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(grp) %>% 
   arrange(grp) %>%
   summarise(total = sum(val)) %>% 
   mutate(grp1 = lag(grp), grp2 = grp, total = total + lag(total)) %>%
   select(grp1, grp2, total) %>%
   na.omit
```

Comment: I get an error. (using dplyr version 0.2 on a Mac with SL version of R 3.1.0). Error in select(`df %>% group_by(grp) %>% arrange(grp) %>% summarise(total = sum(val)) %>%     mutate(grp1 = lag(grp), grp2 = grp, total = total + lag(total))`,  : 
  unused arguments (grp1, grp2, total) .  (It's kind of interesting how the parsing seems to have reversed the orders of operations.)

Comment: It works every time for me.  Try it on a fresh session just in case. I am using dplyr 0.2 from CRAN and "R version 3.1.0 Patched (2014-05-09 r65562)"